# A special usage of "get"

Tags: word-usage, pronouns

In [OELD](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/get) the 25th entry for "get" offers two examples,

> You get(= There are) all these kids hanging around in the street.
>
> They still get cases of typhoid there.

I wonder why "you" is chosen for the first example while "they" is chosen for the second?

Besides, Is "you/they get" structure interchangeable with "there be" structure? Any difference in meaning or usage?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Often, *you/they get X* (or *you/they **have** X*) are indeed interchangeable with *there is X*, or *X exists*. But in general, both alternatives (particularly, *get*) are informal, "slangy" usages.

As you'd expect by considering the literal meaning, in many contexts using *you* rather than *they* tends to suggest that *you personally* might be aware of/affected by whatever *X* is. Correspondingly, using *they* often implies *X happens somewhere else, to other people; it doesn't directly affect **us***.

> [***you get***](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=LjRqAAAAMAAJ&q=%22You%20get%20prostitution%20in%22&dq=%22You%20get%20prostitution%20in%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=CMUlU4WBG8GjhgeG4IH4CA&redir_esc=y) prostitution in any big city.
>    [***they get***](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22seeing%20his%20client%20more%20attentive%20than%20alarmed%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22They%20get%20prostitutes%20in%22&tbm=bks) prostitutes in there.
>    [***there is***](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22seeing%20his%20client%20more%20attentive%20than%20alarmed%22&btnG=Search%20Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1#q=%22There%20is%20prostitution%20in%22&tbm=bks) prostitution in your country too.

*In context,* it wouldn't be ridiculous to replace all of those three usages with either of the other two.

---

Having said that, my advice would be to *accept* (but avoid *using*) either of the "personal pronoun" forms except in the context of a verbal exchange where a native speaker has already used one. It won't always "work" (sound natural). This is particularly so with *they get*, which is normally only used in contexts where it's possible to imagine some class of people ("they") who actually *receive, experience, encounter X*.

Thus, for example,...

> *It's not just an issue for developed nations. You get nuclear power in China too.*  (credible)
>    *They get nuclear power in China as well, you know.*  (unlikely)
>    *They **have** nuclear power in China too.* (unexceptional, "literal", not "slangy")

Note that in *those* examples, #2 is "unlikely" because nuclear power isn't something anyone would normally "get" (#1 is "iffy", but acceptable to most because we're so familiar with the idiomatic usage). But if we replace *nuclear power* by, say, *cholera*, all three versions work (though #1 and #2 are still "slangy").

Comment: OK, I might think your examples could've been more positive.

Comment: @Zhanlong: There's a limit to how long I'm prepared to spend trawling Google Books for three specific instances where the forms could reasonably be transposed. As it was, I had to settle for *prostitutes* rather than *prostitution* on the second example.

Comment: @ZhanlongZheng. I would add that someone living in China would say "we" instead of they: "We get nuclear power in China as well, you know."  Some languages (French and German for those I know, I'd be surprised there if there weren't more) have one personal pronoun to express what is either said in English by *you*, *they* or *we* in this usage of personal pronouns where "people" in general is meant.

Comment: @Laure: I think once you get to ***we*** you can't really avoid acknowledging the *explicit* identification of the subject, in most contexts. You could just about imagine a geneticist, for example, saying *"We get mitochondria in lettuce too, you know"*, but it would strike me as slightly "odd", unless the context made it likely he meant *"that's what **me and my team** have found"*. The idiomatic usage we're focussed on really is "non-personalised" (as in the French ***il** existe des mitochondries dans la laitue*).

Comment: You said you last example was not slangy, but you also said both alternatives (particularly, get) were informal, "slangy" usages. I got confused. @FumbleFingers

Comment: @Zhanlong: As a general principle in this type of construction, *you* is more slangy than *they*, and *get* is more slangy than *have*. The very last example is still a bit "informal" (because of the rather vague "they" = "Chinese people"). But at least it *can* be interpreted literally, and it doesn't use the "extra slangy" elements *you* and *get*. The entire format is somewhat informal, but some versions are more slangy than others. Does that clarify things?

Comment: Understood! Thx!